# Regex to extract everything until it encounters a number after a slash

Tags: regex

I am looking to extract everything form a string but ignore everything after encountering numbers after a slash(alphanumeric allowed)

Examples:

```
http://www.test.com/products/cards/product_code100/12345/something_else
http://www.test.com/products/123abc/45678/
```

Desired output -

```
http://www.test.com/products/cards/product_code100/
http://www.test.com/products/123abc/
```

The following regex gives me everything in backreferences but it'll be great if I could get rid of numbers after a slash-

```
   ^(.*:)//([a-z\-.]+)(:[0-9]+)?(.*)
```

Additional Information - Languauge independent regex needed.

Many Thanks

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com) The purpose of this site is to find help for specific problems where *your own solution* does not work correctly. It is not meant as a site where you can post tasks that other people will solve for you.

Comment: The second example doesn't work, there are numbers after the slash

Comment: There is no such thing as "language independent" regular expressions. There are a few "standards" like POSIX, POSIX extended and Perl regexes that are often copied / supported. But to my knowledge nothing that runs *everywhere*. So - what languages do you need this for?

Comment: Creinig - I said language independent as it is a GUI tool written in Java but we have no access  to its libraries. So I can't use this java.util.regex

Comment: O.R.Mapper -I didn't know it was mandatory to type down what I have tried so far. Most questions don't seem to do that. However, I have tried using negative lookahead to no avail. I'll update my question with sample.

Comment: @thinking_hydrogen it is not mandatory, but showing what you already tried will probably help others to either a) quickly see where you have made a mistake or b) develop a solution to your problem without having to retry things you already tried

Comment: @thinking_hydrogen: Well, mandatory ... it's more about showing that you have put some effort into solving the problem yourself. Time and again, people just post their tasks here in a "write my code for me, I don't want to think about it" manner. It's fine to state "I haven't tried anything, because I don't know where to start." But in that case, be prepared that the answers will not be ready-made solutions for your task, but pointers to places where to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should work with most languages and should produce the desired output

```
(http://.*)(?=/\d+(?!\w+))
```

It takes every character until it finds (lookahead) \ followed by a number.

If you'd try to match

```
http://www.test.com/products/123abc/
or
http://www.test.com/products/123abc
```

it just would not find a match and you could be sure the string checked doesnt encounter a pure number after a slash

Comment: Thanks - It's almost there. But it doesn't seem to match any if there's no number after a slash - Ex. http://www.test.com/products/abc123/

Answer (score 1):

Example in Perl:

```
echo "http://...." | perl -pe 's/(.*\/)\d+\/.*/$1/'
```

or:

```
echo "http://...." | perl -ne 'print "$1\n" if /(.*\/)\d+\/.*/'
```

**Edit:** It's true what @creinig noted in his comment - there is no such thing as generic regex. Nonetheless, Perl is widely used, so it's an option.